# Swift: Decode json response

Tags: json, swift, decode

I have a backend response that has the format:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Id": "blabla",
      "Text": "blabla",
      "Description": "blabla"
    },
    {
      "Id": "blabla",
      "Text": "blabla",
      "Description": "blabla"
    }]
}
```

Which will be the best Swift approach to directly decode the array?

For the moment I have a struct for the response, but I have also to take in account the "Items" key, which hasn't any business logic implication for the project.

```
struct SearchResult: Decodable {
    
    let Id: String
    let Text: String
    let Description: String
}
```

Comment: What makes one approach the best of all?  And show your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is missing a trailing `]` on the end of the array.

Besides that, you just need a wrapper than gives you the `Items` array. This, for example, works fine:

```
let jsonData = """
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Id": "blabla",
      "Text": "blabla",
      "Description": "blabla"
    },
    {
      "Id": "blabla",
      "Text": "blabla",
      "Description": "blabla"
    }
    ]
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct ResultWrapper: Decodable {
    var Items : [SearchResult]
}

struct SearchResult: Decodable {
    
    let Id: String
    let Text: String
    let Description: String
}

do {
    let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResultWrapper.self, from: jsonData)
    print(results.Items) //this is your array
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```